# How can I put three author names in the title of a document using svjour3 document class?

Tags: author, journal, paper, sv-classes

I use `svjour3` to write my paper, but I can not put all author names in one line, how can I correct it? My code is below.

```
\documentclass{svjour3}    
\smartqed 
\journalname{Earth Science Informatics}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}  
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,right=3cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}  
\begin{document}
\title{ Earthquake Magnitude ...}
\author{{Mahshid Fahandezhsadi, Kamal Aghazade, Hamed Fahandezh Sadi}}
\maketitle
 ....
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Note that the actually published articles in the Earth Science Informatics journal look different, see for example https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s12145-020-00441-0.pdf. The final layout is probably done by Springer itself, you don't have to spend too much effort on this for your submission.

Answer (score 1):

you need to separate the names with \and

```
\author{first author  \and scond \and third }
```

Comment: Thank you, but it dose not work!

Comment: shouldn't the \author{} be kept in the preamble? i.e: before \begin{document}?